# Get unique values of separate column after aggregate

Tags: r

I'm using `aggregate` to get the mean of a value as determined by three other values. I'd also like to get a count of how many values met those three criteria.

For example, I have df:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
             col1=sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
             col2 = c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1), 
             col3 = c("a","b","c", "b","a","a","b","a","c","a"),
             col4 = c("yes","no","no", "no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes"))
```

And I run `aggregate` to get the mean for each unique occurence, like:

```
df_agg <- aggregate(col1~col2+col3+col4, df, FUN = mean)
```

What I want to know is that in addition to the mean of rows that have `col2 =1, col3=a, col4=yes` that there are also 3 unique `id` values that meet the criteria. Basically a sample size or n number, but of the unique values. I tried doing `df_agg <- aggregate(id~col2+col3+col4, df, FUN = length)`, but this gives me the total count of `id` rows, I just want the unique ones. 
Something like this, an example of one row from my sample data that would have more than 1 unique id.

An example output for a line that would have more than unique ID:

   `col2      col3      col4     mean    count
|---------|--------|---------|--------|--------|
|    1    |    a   |    yes  |    5   |   3    |
|---------|--------|---------|--------|--------|`

Comment: Can you show your expected output?  It is not clear..  Did you meant `aggregate(id~col2+col3+col4, df, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: It is difficult to understand from the comments.  Please update your post

Comment: Yes! I think this is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I get the mean for the row you showed as 6.25.  Please use correct values instead of some guesses

Comment: Isn't col1 randomly generated, so the mean will be different each time?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  So, you need to have `set.seed`